# After pushing the response of Axios array returns undefined

Tags: asynchronous, axios

I am trying to get the first ten Pokemons using Axios, then pass object's data into array.  After that, I want to filter by weight and return Pokemons, which weight less than argument.

But pushing into array returns undefined. I don't know why? Please, help.

My code:

```
findLessWeight (weight) {
  let firstTenPokemons = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response=> {
      firstTenPokemons.push(response.data);
    })   
  }
  return firstTenPokemons.filter(pokemon=>pokemon.weight < weight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make for loop wait till axios call is done.

```
async findLessWeight (weight) {
  let firstTenPokemons = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    let response = await axios.get(url)
    firstTenPokemons.push(response.data);
  }
  return firstTenPokemons.filter(pokemon=>pokemon.weight < weight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios queries, which are essentially a wrapper of an AJAX call, run asynchronously. So the `return` statement of your function is not waiting for the queries to come back, this means that your function is always returning an empty array. You can make use of [`async await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to wait for the asynchronous queries to run, as well as `axios.all()` to send the requests in parallel (rather than having to wait for them one by one).

In the snippet below, we declare your `findLessWeight` function with the `async` keyword, build the requests in an array, wait for them to execute at the same time using `axios.all` and `await`, then finally return the filtered results. I've also added another function `main` to showcase how you would use `findLessWeight`. It's another async function that wait for `findLessWeight` to finish executing, then logs the results.

***NOTE:*** The function is only logging the weights because the response objects are huge.

```js
async function findLessWeight(w) {
    // array of promises (requests)
    const firstTenPokemonPromises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        // add promises one by one
        firstTenPokemonPromises.push(
            axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
            // we only need the data from the response
            .then(({ data }) => (data))
        );
    }
    // wait for them to execute in parallel
    const firstTenPokemons = await axios.all(firstTenPokemonPromises);
    // return filtered results
    return firstTenPokemons.filter(({ weight }) => (weight < w));
} 
    
async function main() {
    // wait for `findLessWeight` to finish
    const results = await findLessWeight(500);
    // log the corresponding results (just weights in this example)
    console.log(results.map(({ weight }) => (weight)));
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```